# MFC: retrieve button ID programmatically

Tags: c++, mfc, button

I have a CButton object called mouseCtrl, and in the DoDataExchange function, I have the following:

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MCCHECK, mouseMode);
```

Somewhere else in my program, I would like to be able to call a function/method of mouseMode so that I can retrieve the IDC_MCCCHECK id macro properly. Is there a function in MFC that can allow me to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mouseMode.[GetDlgCtrlID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1shyeyy5.aspx)()